# Recognize derived class with identifier not working

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I am trying to create a general interface for derived classes using unique identifier numbers in C++.

This is what my code looks like (you need at least C++11 to compile it):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base
{
    protected:
        int ident;
        Base(int newIdent) : ident(newIdent) { }

    public:
        Base() : ident(0x01) { }
        virtual ~Base() { }           //needed to make class polymorphic
        int getIdent() { return ident; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    protected:
        int answer;
        Derived(int newIdent, int newAnswer) : Base(newIdent), answer(newAnswer) { }

    public:
        Derived(int newAnswer) : Base(0x11), answer(newAnswer) { }
        int getAnswer() { return answer; }
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Base> bPtr = std::make_shared<Derived>(Derived(42));

    std::cout << "ident = 0x" << std::hex << bPtr->getIdent() << std::dec << "\n";
    if(bPtr->getIdent() & 0xF0 == 1)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Derived> dPtr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(bPtr);
        std::cout << "answer = " << dPtr->getAnswer() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Of course you should expect that the program outputs `ident = 0x11` and `answer = 42`, but it doesn't, because it exists normally after the `ident = 0x11` line. I also did some examination with GDB and the disassembly of the critical `if` condition check in the main function confirms the issue:

```
   0x0000000000400f46 <+196>:   call   0x401496 <std::__shared_ptr<Base, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::operator->() const>
   0x0000000000400f4b <+201>:   mov    rdi,rax
   0x0000000000400f4e <+204>:   call   0x4012bc <Base::getIdent()>
   0x0000000000400f53 <+209>:   mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000000000400f58 <+214>:   test   al,al
   0x0000000000400f5a <+216>:   je     0x400fb7 <main()+309>
```

When you break at `*0x400f53`, rax nicely keeps the correct value (`0x11`), but the following instruction just overwrites rax with zero, `test` sets the zero flag and the `je` instruction jumps to the end of the main function because the zero flag is set. What is going on here? Am I missing something or is the compiler (`g++ 4.9.2` with `x86_64-linux-gnu` target) generating wrong instructions?

Comment: `std::make_shared<Derived>(Derived(42))` Why the extra copy?

Comment: Define "it terminates".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It exists normally.

Comment: Then your `if` condition is not evaluating to `true`. Look at it a little more closely. Add an `else` clause with some `std::cout` statements for debugging.

Comment: [This article](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/) was made for you, it seems! You did not complete your divide-and-conquer debugging, and so this testcase is not minimal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always compile with warnings enabled. Your problem is an order of operations issue where `&` has lower precedence than `==`, so you need:

```
if ((bPtr->getIdent() & 0xF0) == 1)
```

Although then you're comparing against the wrong thing, so you *really* want:

```
if ((bPtr->getIdent() & 0xF0) == 0x10)
```

---

In this case, you would see this from gcc:

```
main.cpp:32:32: warning: suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of '&' [-Wparentheses]
     if(bPtr->getIdent() & 0xF0 == 1)
                           ~~~~~^~~~
```

or this from clang:

```
main.cpp:32:25: warning: & has lower precedence than ==; == will be evaluated first [-Wparentheses]
    if(bPtr->getIdent() & 0xF0 == 1)
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:32:25: note: place parentheses around the '==' expression to silence this warning
    if(bPtr->getIdent() & 0xF0 == 1)
                        ^
                          (        )
main.cpp:32:25: note: place parentheses around the & expression to evaluate it first
    if(bPtr->getIdent() & 0xF0 == 1)
                        ^
       (                      )
```

Comment: It's a shame clang uses that misleading "will be evaluated first" terminology.